# XSL count() within a choose element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a kind of scoreboard and want to calculate the winning team. But unfortunately i cannot count the number of appearances of the id value. Here is the example xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="winner.xsl" ?>
<wm>
    <game>
        <team id='de' />
        <team id='fr' />
        <result>4:2</result>
    </game>
    <game>
        <team id='us' />
        <team id='de' />
        <result>4:2</result>
    </game>
    <game>
        <team id='de' />
        <team id='fr' />
        <result>3:2</result>
    </game>
    <game>
        <team id='de' />
        <team id='fr' />
        <result>1:3</result>
    </game>
</wm>
```

and the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="wm/game/result">
<xsl:variable name="tore1" select="substring-before(.,':')"/>
<xsl:variable name="tore2" select="substring-after(.,':')"/>

 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$tore1 &gt; $tore2">
         <xsl:value-of select="../team[1]/@id"/><br />
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="../team[2]/@id"/><br />
     </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

I set the winner of a game by comparing the goals of the result and select the team[1] or team[2]. The output is:

```
de
us
de
fr
```

But now I am stuck with the counting of the appearances of the countries. If I set the count() on the XPath expression like

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../team[1]/@id)" />
```

it results in:

```
1
1
1
1
```

Also

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../team[@id = 'de'])"/>
```

outside the choose statement did the same output. I would like to have the following output

```
2 de
1 us
1 fr
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a grouping problem, before it''s a counting problem. Do you have a list of the participating teams - or do you need to group the games by whatever teams are listed in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting the number of wins of a **known** team is easy. Consider the following example:

```
<xsl:template match="/wm">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="'de'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="home-wins" select="count(game[team[1]/@id=$id][substring-before(result, ':') > substring-after(result, ':')])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="away-wins" select="count(game[team[2]/@id=$id][substring-after(result, ':') > substring-before(result, ':')])"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$home-wins + $away-wins"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
2 de
```

Comment: And it's not too hard to combine that with Meunchian grouping to identify all of the teams represented in the input document, and output the number of wins for each.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The answer of @michael.hor257k works fine. I tried also to apply the Meunchian grouping. I think I got it. Thanks for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


<xsl:key name="teamsByID" match="game/team" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="wm">

  <xsl:for-each select="game/team[count(. | key('teamsByID', @id)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tore1" select="count(../../game[team[1]/@id=$id][substring-before(result,':') > substring-after(result, ':')])" />
    <xsl:variable name="tore2" select="count(../../game[team[2]/@id=$id][substring-after(result,':') > substring-before(result, ':')])" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$tore1 + $tore2"/>  -  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><br />
  </xsl:for-each>   

</xsl:template>
```